# Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined when setting contractAbi

Tags: web3js

Currently i have

```
private abiToken: [ { "constant": true, "inputs": any, "name": "name", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "string", "value": "ThankYou" } ], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [ { "name": "_giver", "type": "address" } ], "name": "totalEtherGivenOf", "outputs": [ { "name": "numberOfEther", "type": "uint256", "value": "0" } ], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": any, "name": "decimals", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "uint8", "value": "0" } ], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "name": "_from", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_to", "type": "address" } ], "name": "createTokenProxy", "outputs": [ { "name": "success", "type": "bool" } ], "payable": true, "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "name": "_to", "type": "address" } ], "name": "presentToken", "outputs": [ { "name": "success", "type": "bool" } ], "payable": true, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [ { "name": "_giver", "type": "address" } ], "name": "etherGivenInMonth", "outputs": [ { "name": "numberOfEther", "type": "uint256", "value": "0" } ], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [ { "name": "_receiver", "type": "address" } ], "name": "balanceOf", "outputs": [ { "name": "token", "type": "uint256", "value": "0" } ], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": any, "name": "symbol", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "string", "value": "ThankYou" } ], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": any, "name": "price", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "uint256", "value": "5000000000000000000" } ], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "name": "_to", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_value", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "transfer", "outputs": any, "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [ { "name": "_receiver", "type": "address" } ], "name": "tokenReceivedInMonth", "outputs": [ { "name": "token", "type": "uint256", "value": "0" } ], "payable": false, "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "name": "_tokenName", "type": "string", "index": 0, "typeShort": "string", "bits": "", "displayName": "&thinsp;<span class=\"punctuation\">_</span>&thinsp;token Name", "template": "elements_input_string", "value": "ThankYou" }, { "name": "_tokenSymbol", "type": "string", "index": 1, "typeShort": "string", "bits": "", "displayName": "&thinsp;<span class=\"punctuation\">_</span>&thinsp;token Symbol", "template": "elements_input_string", "value": "ThankYou" }, { "name": "_tokenPrice", "type": "uint256", "index": 2, "typeShort": "uint", "bits": "256", "displayName": "&thinsp;<span class=\"punctuation\">_</span>&thinsp;token Price", "template": "elements_input_uint", "value": "5" } ], "payable": false, "type": "constructor" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [ { "indexed": true, "name": "_from", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": true, "name": "_to", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "_value", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "Transfer", "type": "event" } ];`
```

on the service i test the function in my contract that deployed on blockchain by calling the function :

```
testTY_Token(){

    this.connectToNode();
    let token_TY = this.web3.eth.contract(this.abiToken).at("0x28a5296F54E68DCDb7502E49a86195555Bae21F0");
    let address_from = this.web3.eth.accounts[0];
    let address_to = "0xf8f62dB380b34A77F162e485fDf881140b6f23fE";
    let amount = 5;
    token_TY.presentToken(address_to, {from: address_from, value: this.web3.toWei(amount, "ether")}, function (error, transactionHash) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      return transactionHash;
    });
  }

on console log at debug mode i got error at the line let token_TY = this.web3.eth.contract(this.abiToken).at("0x28a5296F54E68DCDb7502E49a86195555Bae21F0");

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at u (eval at webpackJsonp.97.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:1:25611)
    at p.at (eval at webpackJsonp.97.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:1:27430)
    at EthereumServices.webpackJsonp.264.EthereumServices.testTY_Token (ethereum-service.ts:161)
    at MyProfileComponent.webpackJsonp.261.MyProfileComponent.testTY (myprofile.component.ts:30)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (MyProfileComponent.html:80)
    at handleEvent (core.es5.js:11914)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13206)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.es5.js:12794)
    at dispatchEvent (core.es5.js:8814)
    at core.es5.js:9406
```

I'm using metamask provider that initially injected.

Some body can help to point out where i'm wrong ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This is because your declaration should use = not :

Change to:

```
private abiToken = [ { "constant": ... } ];`
```